# Page won't show special characters

Tags: character, meta

So I know this is a common problem with stuff like the charset, but the weird thing is that this works on a page with the same set-up/template, but not on this one!

So basically, my problem is that the page won't show Norwegian characters like å and ø.

Here's the page with the problem: http://suldal.underbakke.net/register.php
and here's one with the same template but working: http://suldal.underbakke.net/

(On the second one, it's a "å" in 4th post, in the name)

Comment: Where is saved your text?

Comment: What do you mean? On the first page it's supposed to say "Første Namn" instead of "F*weird symbol*rste Namn", and on the second page it's "Håkon Underbakke" where it's supposed to be.

Comment: But is your text hardcoded or saved in a database?

Comment: Oh, no it's put directly into the file, not database. Neither of them are from the database, both directly "hardcoded", because the stream is just a design demo.

Comment: My suggestion is that your file is not saved as UTF-8

Comment: Saved? What do you mean, or how do I do that. I have it in the meta charset tag, but I don't know..

Comment: Also, I tried re-editing the page it works on with my FTP manager to check if it is it that does it but it still worked, so it can't be my ftp file editor (Coda 2, mac)

Comment: try with another editor and look at the encoding, for example with textwrangler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is declared as being in UTF-8 encoding, but it is in fact windows-1252 (or iso-8859-1) encoded. You can see this by manually selecting the encoding while viewing the page in a browser; browsers typically have a View menu where you can select the encoding.

Thus, as a quick fix, you could just change `utf-8` to `windows-1252` in the `meta` tag.

As a different workaround, you could replace the “special characters” (Scandinavian letters) by [HTML entities](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/guide/entities.html), e.g. “ø” by `&oslash;`. Depending on the authoring software, you might need to do something special to achieve this (e.g., enter “HTML mode”), because an authoring tool might automatically convert “&” to `&amp;`.

As the best solution, find out how to save a file in UTF-8 encoding in the authoring program you are using, and keep the `meta` tag as is. This is typically either an option in the general settings of the program or a choice you can make in a “Save As” command.

Comment: Perfect and wonderful answer Jukka! I went into the Coda 2 settings, but the encoding is on utf-8, however I saw that "Default Line Endings" was on Mac OS X/Linux, maybe changing that to Windows will help. If it doesn't, I always have that quick fix. Again, thank you!

Comment: @Schart, line endings are a different issue and do not affect this problem (it relates to which control character(s) is used to indicate end of line, not how characters are encoded).

Comment: Yeah I noticed. Still the quick fix did fix it for that page, and since it was that page only, I think that should be good enough for now.